# How do I design an runtime-assign-valued enum?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

```
class MyFileOperation
{
    int iUserReadPos;
    string sArticleBuffer;
    string sExtraInfo;
    enum Offset
    {
        ofsUserReadPos = 0, ofsArticleBuffer, ofsExtraInfo
    };
public:
    MyFileOperation(string filename)
    {
        /*By reading the file, I know the values of iUserReadPos, sArticlBuffer and sExtraInfo*/
        /*Then I want to assign the values Offset items*/
        ofsUserReadPos = 0;
        ofsArticlBuffer = sizeof(iUserReadPos);
        ofsExtraInfo = sizeof(string::size_type) + sArticlBuffer.length();
    }
    void MoveTo(Offset ofs)
    {
        f.seekp(ios::beg+ofs);
    }

    void SomeUsingOfMoveTo()
    {
        MoveTo(ofsExtraInfo);
    }
};
```

I want to assign valus for the Offset items, and directly use these values conveniently.
Of course this code can't compile. I wonder if there is new c++ features such as enum class or other design can solve this problem.

Comment: Unrelated: Quoting cppreference: *f the first enumerator does not have an initializer, the associated value is zero.*. `ofsUserReadPos` doesn't need the initializer. It's guaranteed to be zero.

Comment: That's not possible in C++. Enum values are compile-time constants.

Answer (score 1):

**No. It's not possible.**

> An enumeration is a distinct type (3.9.2) with **named constants**. Its name becomes an enum-name, within its scope. *(7.2 Enumeration declarations, C++17)*

What you are asking is an oxymoron design, because `enum` is supposed to be a compiled time constant, which (like an acid test) can be even used as a template parameter.

You may have to use any other normal variable to accomplish the task.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple way. You need to add a vector to record the real offset values;

```
enum Offset
    {
        ofsUserReadPos = 0, ofsArticleBuffer, ofsExtraInfo, ofsCount
    };

vector<size_t> vtOffset = vector<size_t>(ofsCount);
```

When you want a corresponding offset, just call
`vtOffset[ofsUserReadPos]`.

Comment: Please explain why? @user4581301

Comment: @v78 The comment made sense before Zhang's edit, it was a small optimization to avoid needing a custom constructor for the class to handle resizing the `vector`.